# Swap nodes in a singly-linked list

Tags: c, pointers, swap, singly-linked-list

I am trying to swap two nodes. For example if the nodes are `a` and `b` I am passing the pointers
`(a-1)->next` and `(b-1)->next` which are basically nodes `a` and `b`.

```
void swap(struct stack **a,struct stack **b)
{
    struct stack *temp1 = *a, *temp2 = *b, *temp3 = *b;      
    *a = *b; 
    (*b)->next = (temp1)->next;
    temp2 = temp1;
    (temp2)->next = temp3->next;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? When I am trying to print the nodes after calling the function it's an infinite loop. Please help.

Comment: Although You can wasp only data, if you want instead node!

Comment: Not much C++ there, only C. If you used C++ you should use [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack), and use the existing [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) instead.

Comment: I guess it would be far more easier to simply swap the data:  `data_type temp = (*a)->data; (*a)->data = (*b)->data; (*b)->data = temp;`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan did u mean..switching data from those nodes??well what i want is not that.i want to switch the nodes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I don't see the point. The large of his code may be C++ and since C++ includes all that which is C there's an argument that it is in fact C++; no? Also, he may be implementing this himself and cannot use certain technologies.

Comment: Is this a school project or a special type of list or something?  If not, `std::list` or `std::swap` has already taken care of this.

Comment: @MrE a-1 and b-1..i just meant the previous nodes.doesnt really matter.

Comment: @C.Lang The point is that (1) C++ offers you facilities that do all of this for you, and there's no reason to not make use of that and (2) even disregarding that, there are things like double pointers that could be references to pointers and gratuitous `struct`s sprinkled throughout.

Comment: @guys whats the problem with my code.. :)

Comment: @zeta like i said thats not my requirement.i want to switch nodes not just the data.

Comment: Well, we have ___no idea what `struct stack` is___. So we cannot help you until you provide a [complete example which shows the error beside your expected behaviour](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @us2012- The reason to not make use of that is because you're asked to in order to understand it. This is likely a school project and the professor is not allowing OP to do so until OP's done it himself. I understand the arguments against this style of teaching as I've read them here a hundred times before. That doesn't change the fact that some of us, including me, are subject to it. There's no rule that you have to use the `STL` it's just the smartest thing to do.

Comment: There is a node that points to `a` and you have to change it to point to `b`. There is also a node that points to `b` and you have to change it to point to `a`. You however don't have these nodes, so you cannot switch `a` and `b`.

Comment: @n.m.: he is passing pointers to the pointers to `a` and `b`. Swapping nodes like this *is* possible, assuming that those points point to the previous node pointers...

Comment: @CodeRat : please find my updated answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Why Infinite loop?

Infinite loop is because of self loop in your list *after* calling `swap()` function. In `swap()` code following statement is buggy.

```
(*b)->next = (temp1)->next;
```

**Why?**: Because after the assignment statement in `swap()` function `temp1`'s next starts  pointing to `b` node. And `node[b]`'s next point to itself in a loop. And the **self loop** is reason for **infinite loop**, somewhere in your code where you traverse linked list.

Below I drawn to show how `swap()` works step-by-step. May be this help you to understand your *error*:

You didn't mention but I am assuming linked list having following relation between `a` and `b`: (*read red comments*)

**(step-1):**

```
+----+----+----+      +---+----+----+
|      one     |----->|    two      |
+----+----+----+      +---+---+-----+
  ^     ^              ^    ^
  |     |              |    |
  |    *a              |   *b
  |                    | 
 temp1                temp2, temp3     "after assignment to temp variables"

(step-2):                   ^
                            | 
*a = *b                     | *a       "<--- next step"
```

**(step-3):**  The buggy statement

```
(*b)->next = (temp1)->next;          "Change link: (temp1)->next; is `two` node"
                                     " *b is `two`,   So Self loop" 


+----+----+----+      +---+----+----+ <---|  
|      one     |      |    two      |-----|
+----+----+----+      +---+---+-----+
  ^                    ^    ^    ^
  |                    |    |    |
  |                    |   *b    *a
  |                    | 
 temp1                temp2, temp3    "  after assignment to temp"
```

See `(temp1)->next;` is actually `b` and you are assigning `(*b)->next = (*b)` by doing `(*b)->next = (temp1)->next;` hence adding a self loop.

**(step-4):**
I think with the diagram you can easily understand what last two lines of your `swap()` code are doing:

```
temp2 = temp1;
(temp2)->next = temp3->next;
```

Following is my diagram for this two lines:

```
temp2 = temp1;         
+----+----+----+      +---+----+----+ <---|
|      one     |      |    two      |-----|  "<--- Self loop"
+----+----+----+      +---+---+-----+
  ^                    ^    ^    ^
  |                    |    |    |
  |                    |   *b    *a
  |                    | 
  temp2 = temp1;      temp3
```

**(step-5):**  Even last line of your function `swap()`  left loop as below:

```
 (temp2)->next = temp3->next;  " last line of your code"

+----+----+----+      +---+----+----+ <---|
|      one     |----->|    two      |-----|  "<-- Self loop"
+----+----+----+      +---+---+-----+
  ^                    ^    ^    ^
  |                    |    |    |
  |                    |   *b    *a
  |                    | 
temp2 = temp1;          temp3
```

So loop still there at `two` node so infinite loop.

### How to swap two nodes in single linked list?

One way is swap node's data instead of swapping node's position it self in linked list (*as I commented to your question*). But ***you wants to swap node's*** position in list.
Well this good! if node data size is larger, that time its better to swap node's position rather then swap node's data(*swapping data will be bad choice*)

Because you having **single linked list**, to swap any two arbitrary nodes in list you *need* there *previous node addresses* too. (*this is the point you don't consider in your swapping logic*)

**WHY need previous pointers?**:
Suppose after some successful insert(push) operations, your list becomes as follows:

```
 0  <--------TOP - "head"
 9  <--p  
 2    
 6  <--q           
 5
```

A horizontal diagram-  Suppose *you want to swap* say two nodes `(q)`  and `(p)`:

```
+---+    +---+    +---+    +---+    +---+                               
| 0 |--->| 9 |--->| 2 |--->| 6 |--->| 5 |---
+---+    +---+    +---+    +---+    +---+  |                                
 ^        ^                  ^            null  
 |        |                  | 
 |       (q)                (p)   
 (head)
```

As I said, to swap we need previous pointers. You need to think about following
(*In theory, I am writing for specific nodes `(p)` and `(q)` just to keep explanation simple. but my implementation is quit general*):

In list previous pointers:

```
node[0] points to node[9] that is (q), and 
node[2] points to node[6] that is (p)
```

And

```
node[9] points to node[2]
node[6] points to node[5]
```

**NOTICE:** If you want to swap two nodes say `node[ 9 ]`  and `node[ 6 ]` then you should use pointers of the nodes previous to these two nodes.
For example: two swap `node[ 9 ]` and `[ 6 ]`, you also need to change next pointer of `node[ 0 ]` and next pointer of `node[ 2 ]` in above diagram.

**How would be the list after swapping this two nodes?**

```
+---+    +---+    +---+    +---+    +---+                               
| 0 |--->| 6 |--->| 2 |--->| 9 |--->| 5 |---
+---+    +---+    +---+    +---+    +---+  |                                
 ^        ^                  ^            null  
 |        |                  | 
 |       (p)                (q)   
 (head)
```

What is now in previous nodes `[o]` and `[2]`?
After swapping, In list previous pointers

```
node[0] points to node[6] that is (q), and 
node[2] points to node[9] that is (p)
```

And

```
node[9] points to node[5]
node[6] points to node[2]
```

So if you want to swap two nodes; there immediate previous node also effects and because list is single link list you need previous pointers too.

**How to find previous node pointers?**

Suppose you want to swap any two nodes `node[p]` and `node[q]` then you can use `head pointer` to find previous node.

So swap function **syntax** (*In my implementation*) is like:

```
void swap(struct stack **head, // head node 
          struct stack **a,    // first candidate node to swap
          struct stack **b);   // first candidate node to swap
```

And you will call function like:

```
swap(&head, &p, &q);
```

**Definition:** (*To understand code please read comments I added at almost each line*)

```
void swap(struct stack **head, 
          struct stack **a, 
          struct stack **b){
  // first check if a agrgument is null                 
  if( (*head) == NULL ||               // Empty list         
        (*a) == NULL || (*b) == NULL){     // one node is null  
       // Nothing to swap, just return 
        printf("\n Nothing to swap, just return \n");
        return;
  }     

  // find previos nodes
  struct stack* pre_a = get_prevnd(*head, *a);
  struct stack* pre_b = get_prevnd(*head, *b);

  //Now swap previous node's next
  if(pre_a) pre_a->next = (*b); // a's previous become b's previous, and 
  if(pre_b) pre_b->next = (*a); // b's previous become a's previous

  //Now swap next fiels of candidate nodes  
  struct stack* temp = NULL;  
    temp = (*a)->next;
  (*a)->next = (*b)->next;
  (*b)->next = temp;

  //change head: if any node was a head 
  if((*head)==(*a)) 
     *head = *b;
  else 
     if((*head)==(*b))  
        *head = *a;
}
```

In `swap()` function you can notice that I call a helper function `get_prevnd(, );`. This function returns address of previous node in list. In The function `get_prevnd(, );`, first argument is list head and second argument is node for which you are looking for.

```
// find previous node function()
struct stack* get_prevnd(
                 struct stack* head, 
                 struct stack* a
                ){
    if(head == a){
        // node[a] is first node 
        return NULL;
    }
    struct stack* temp = head; // temp is current node
    struct stack* pre_a = NULL; 

    while(temp && temp!=a){ //search while not reach to end or the node
        pre_a = temp;          // find previous node   
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(temp!=a){// node[a] not present in list
        fprintf(stderr, "\n error: node not found!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // bad technique to exit()
    }
    return pre_a;   
}
```

And fortunately the code is WORKING :). Below is link for online test of this code. I have tested for  various kind of inputs.

CodePad: [**To Swap node in single linked list.**](http://codepad.org/3YaGfYxm) Please check output.

<sub>And sorry for bad English</sub>

Comment: *let me know if you need more help. I feel @thkala given you correct answer I wanted just to show you error in your code*

Comment: I'll +1 this one, just for the ASCII art :-)

Comment: well thanx..but i think that problem will be rectified in the following 2 lines of code.(i mean the infinite thing).sorry if i am wrong.

Comment: yeah you are right.but the code that @thkala gave...seems its not working properly. i mean a made a stack push(&head,5);
push(&head,6);
q=head;
push(&head,2);
push(&head,9);
p=head;
push(&head,0); and i called with swap(&p,&q) initially the stack is 0 9 2 6 5 but the result i am geting is 0 9 5 and what i am supposed to get is 0 6 2 9 5

Comment: :) but the thing is i have been on this problem for hours.his code should have worked theoretically but why is iy failing.

Comment: thanx a lot for the help but i found a new thing now.thkalas code works but basically calling of the function is not okay.

Comment: My co-worker found a bug in these two lines: `if((*head)==(*a)) *head = *b;` `if((*head)==(*b)) *head = *a;`. The second `if` should be `else if`.

Comment: @TomSirgedas thanks, can you explain why? there is one case that I could have think when `a == b`, in that case I will get a loop in linked list. -- so yes it is buggy

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Let's say `(*head)==(*a)`, then you'll do `*head = *b`. So far, this is OK. But now the next line's condition `(*head)==(*b)` will be met and you'll set `*head = *a` (which is incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for cut-and-paste code, but didn't find it.  If anyone is still interested, this is the answer.  I did the brute force analysis of all 3 cases.

```
// swaps nodes at locations *sp and *tp
struct stack *s = *sp; // store locations to prevent overwritten bugs
struct stack *t = *tp;
if(&t->next == sp) { // order u (tp)-> t (sp)-> s -> ...
    t->next = s->next;
    s->next = t;
    *tp = s;
} else if(&s->next == tp) { // order u (sp)-> s (tp)-> t -> ...
    s->next = t->next;
    t->next = s;
    *sp = t;
} else { // disconnected u (sp)->s -> ..., v (tp)->t -> ...
    struct stack *next = s->next;
    s->next = t->next;
    t->next = next;
    *sp = t;
    *tp = s;
}             
// If you track the end of your list, it be the one pointing to NULL.                                           
if(s->next == NULL) {                                  
    end = &s->next;                                 
} else if(t->next == NULL) {                           
    end = &t->next;                                 
}
```

Note: This code works if sp == tp, but assumes you don't have the pathological case where BOTH &s->next == tp && &t->next == sp (starting with cycle).

Answer (score -3):

```
        "KING KHAN"
```

`SwapanyTwoNodeData(int, int);`  this function take two integer as parameter and swap these

node data.

```
1->2->6->3->4->5
```

`SwapanyTwoNodeData (2,4);`

```
1->3->6->2->4->5
```

100% Working Function. . . . Enjoy.

```
void Swap_Any_Two_Locations_data(int x,int x1){

   if(head!=NULL){     
     int count=1,count1=1;     
     Node *temp,*temp1;
     temp=head;
     temp1=head;
     while(temp->next!=NULL && count!=x ){
         temp=temp->next;
         count++;
     }
     while(temp1->next!=NULL && count1!=x1){
         temp1=temp1->next;
         count1++;
     }
     if(count==x && count1==x1){
       int z=0;
       z=temp->info;
       temp->info=temp1->info;
       temp1->info=z;
       cout<<"Data Swapped"<<endl;
    }
  }
}
```