# C: Removing a node from singly-LinkedList1 and inserting it at the head of singly-LinkedList2

Tags: c, pointers, singly-linked-list

I'm doing a computer science project that simulates an operating system's process scheduler. I have **multiple singly-linked lists**, and need to **move nodes** between them.
I am trying to write a general **function** to accomplish this, but I think my **weakness using pointers** is holding me back.

How do I implement the desired function? So far I have the following:

```
typedef struct process_list_struct ProcessList;

struct process_list_struct
{
    Process proc;
    ProcessList* next;
};

void change_lists(ProcessList* node, ProcessList* newlist)
{
    ProcessList* temp = NULL;
    debug_printf("change_lists reached\n");
    temp = node;
    if(!node)
    {
        debug_printf("Error: change_lists failed!\n");
        return;
    }
    node = node->next;
    temp->next = newlist;
    newlist = temp;
    return;
}
```

The result is strange... I end up with the first list containing **only** the node I wanted to move and **everything else** missing (pretty much the opposite effect than what I wanted), and the *newlist* (tested as starting empty) remains empty.

I have looked up implementations of node swaps in single lists and have seen people use **double pointers** instead, but that's really confusing me. Can someone please show me how to apply them in this case? I tried using them, but them combined with referencing pointer elements of structs got really confusing.

Help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You following four steps are wrong to shift node from one list to other list:

```
temp = node
node = node->next;
temp->next = newlist;
newlist = temp;
```

See below I shown with a diagram:

Suppose you have node in linked **list-1:**

```
    +---+----+----+      +----+----+----+      +---+----+----+
  ->|   zero      |----->|      one     |----->|    two      |--
    +---+----+----+      +----+----+----+      +---+---+-----+
                             ^   ^
                             |   |
                             |  node 
    after temp=node        temp
```

What after: `node = node->next;` things becomes like:

```
    +---+----+----+      +----+----+----+      +---+----+----+
  ->|   zero      |----->|      one     |----->|    two      |--
    +---+----+----+      +----+----+----+      +---+---+-----+
                             ^                        ^
                             |                        |
                             temp                    node
```

after `temp->next = newlist;` this ?

```
    +---+----+----+      +----+----+----+      +---+----+----+
  ->|   zero      |----->|      one     |      |    two      |--
    +---+----+----+      +----+----+----+      +---+---+-----+
                             ^       |                ^
                             |       |                |
                             temp    |                node     
                                     |
                                     |
                                     |    "head node"
                                     |   +---+----+----+   +---+----+---+
         "This is your list-2"       |-->|   FIVE      |-->|   SIX      |--
                                         +---+---+-----+   +---+----+---+ 
                                          newlist
```

your lats step `newlist = temp;` ?

```
                           newlist                    
                            |
                            ▼ "head node"
    +---+----+----+      +----+----+----+      +---+----+----+
  ->|   zero      |----->|      one     |      |    two      |--
    +---+----+----+      +----+----+----+      +---+---+-----+
                             ^       |                ^
                             |       |                |
                             temp    |                node     
                                     |
                                     |    
                                     |   +---+----+----+   +---+----+---+
         "This is your list-2"       |-->|   FIVE      |-->|    SIX     |--
                                         +---+---+-----+   +---+----+---+
```

**This is What you do. but  it is not what you wants ?**
you algorithm to shift node from one list to other list is wrong additionally you made technical mistake that, you are passing pointer by values (you need pointer to pointer to reflect changes at calling function)

because you wants to shift node from one list to other, and pass pointers of `node` in one list and head of other list, You need to pass pointer of pointer to reflect change in calling function, hence your declaration seems to me wrong:

```
void change_lists(ProcessList* node, ProcessList* newlist)
```

I think it should be:

```
void change_lists(ProcessList** node, ProcessList** newlist)
```

Write your code to shift node with this prototype.

**Edit**: (suggestion)

The basic problem in your code is that to shift a node (*e.g. one*) in list one you do not change pointer to previous nodes (*zero node in diagram*), You need to makes

```
[zero] ---> [two]
```

Similar mistake made by @CodeRat in his list: [**Swap nodes in a singly-linked list**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315914/swap-nodes-in-a-singly-linked-list?answertab=votes#tab-top)

I given him an answer that I think will help you to implement you code.

old answer:

One mistake that I can find: Instead of

```
*temp = *node;
```

you should write

```
temp = node;
```

address not values

doing `*temp = *node;` is Undefined behavior because you don't allocates memory for temp, You need to assign address in temp. (temp points to NULL) because you wants to shift node from one list to other list thats why you need `temp = node;`

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. My previous code was correct, but when I attempted double pointers and then rewrote my first attempt after giving up, I made that silly mistake! Thanks Grijesh!

Comment: Using the ProcessList** prototyping, what would I have to change in my actualy function? I really don't understand the referencing that needs to happen in function :(

Comment: Yeah, the pictures you created (**thank you so much for the effort!**) sum up basically what I want to do... do you think my code is correct for doing this?

Comment: I'd be grateful for any feedback or criticism that I can learn from or use to help me improve my answer."

Answer (score 0):

I believe your prototype is wrong, it's too simplistic.

You can't move a node of a singly-linked list without somehow having the ability to afterwards change which node is considered the start of the list.

Otherwise, what happens if you move the first node? The surrounding code would retain the pointer, but the node is now logically part of the destination list for the move, and all is brokened.

Also, the same applies for the destination list: what if it's empty before the move?

Comment: That's what I was attempting to use  'ProcessList* temp = NULL;
temp=node;' to do, in a similar fashion to "int_swap()": retain the initial pointer for later reassignment. Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's clearly wrong in this code is doing `*temp = *node;` when `temp` = `NULL`. You cannot dereference a NULL pointer.

Also, if `node` belongs to a singly-linked list, you can't remove it from the list if you only have a pointer to `node`. To remove it, you need to change the node that points to `node` so it doesn't point to `node` anymore and instead points to `NULL` or to the node that follows `node`. If you used a doubly-linked list, you could find the neighbor nodes to `node` given only a pointer to `node`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a node from single linked list, its previous node is required. The previous node has to be linked to the next node.

If the previous node is available to the function, then fine, but if not, then one has to start looking from the head. Thus, the head is required.

The heads for both the lists are required. And since remove or add operations can change the head pointers, it is natural to pass them as pointer-to-pointers.