# sorting the linked lists by modifying the links

Tags: c++, c, linked-list

i'm trying to sort the linked list by modifying the links not swapping the data.i'm using selection sort.i don't know where i am going wrong.i'm beginner please help me.

```
struct node
{
    int   data;
    node* link;
};

node* p;    

void sort()
{
    node* temp = p;
    node* save;
    node* prev;
    node* tprev;
    node* push = new node;

    tprev = NULL;
    for (; temp != NULL; temp = temp->link)
    {
        push = temp->link;
        for (; push != NULL; push = push->link)
        {
            if (push->data<temp->data)
            {
                save->link  = temp->link;
                temp->link  = push->link;
                push->link  = save->link;
                prev->link  = temp;
                tprev->link = push;
            }

            prev = push;
        }

        tprev = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please consistently format the code, this looks bad.  Clean code, is the first step to working code. Also, place spaces between operators.

Comment: i'm  extremely i'm new-bie here i don't know how to format it would be helpful if you say how i can do

Comment: This: `save->link=...` isn't looking so hot. `save` points to *what* exactly? And if this is to be done with *no* value-movement (link adjustment only) the word `new` should appear exactly *zero* times in this code, so the wheels have come off before you even reach your first loop.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan can you please pin point where i'm going wrong

Comment: @saimadan your swapping nodes logic( code)  is not correct you don't consider parent node's link. Read [Swap nodes in a singly-linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315914/swap-nodes-in-a-singly-linked-list/15316061#15316061)

Comment: @meaning-matters I was about to say very nice formatting, just add space in `temp=p;` and in if comparison

Comment: @meaning-matters thanks a lot from my next question i will try to format in the way you did

Comment: @meaning-matters p is the head of the linked list

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i looked at the code again i'm unable to find the error can you please post answer

Comment: Too bad you chose selection-sort. at least bubble has a fighting chance of becoming O(n) if the list is actually sorted. None-the-less you need to spend some time in a debugger as well as reviewing your pointer-work. There are at least two *indeterminate* pointers in this code that are dereferenced and invoking undefined behavior. And the lone (unneeded) dynamic allocation `node* push = new node;` leaks memory almost immediately into the loops : `push = temp->link;`

Comment: @saimadan I wish I could answer But there is sorting logic also I posted my comment just regarding node swapping I learn How to correctly swap code you can read my answer I have linked.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan very nice post

Comment: @saimadan  thanks Did you find why your swapping is not correct? Read [Linked List Bubble Sort¶](http://www.sal.ksu.edu/faculty/tim/CMST302/study_guide/topic7/bubble.html)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan i understood the post you linked but i did not understand the error in mine

Comment: @saimadan Ok I don't promise, but let me try to correct.

Comment: @WhozCraig save->link is pointing to the next node of temp(temp is the first one of the two nodes which are to be swapped) and can you please tell me why am i not supposed to use new

Comment: @saimadan I realized/I think there are more changes required, sorry but I can do immediately in case if you don't gets an answer I will answer @ weekend evening.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan okay i will wait

Comment: @saimadan can you link rest of your code? put it at codepad and post me a comment here.

Comment: @saimadan No, it isn't. Where in the posted code is there *ever* a `save = ...` to assign a valid address into the `save` pointer. *Any* dereference operation (`*save` or `save->`) or even *evaluating* the address in `save` is **undefined behavior**. And `prev` has the same issue on the *initial* pass of the inner-loop. As I said, you need to review your pointer work. And regarding using `new` for this algorithm, because C++ isn't java. `p = new Type; p = somethine-else;` is an outright memory leak, again related to language pointer-usage familiarity.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan http://codepad.org/o9JFImJy

Comment: @WhozCraig frankly  speaking i am unable to understand the technical terms you speak like memory leak.i'm a beginner. it would be helpful if you provide some source where i can learn pointers

Comment: @saimadan That is somewhat my point. Without a reasonable working knowledge of how pointers *work* in the language, any *solution* code posted  will not be of much use. The web has *tons* of examples from the most basic to the most esoteric regarding how pointers work. [A solution like this](http://ideone.com/TFfvuE), while correct, isn't going to do much good without the fundamentals, and I think that is where you should be concentrating. Such a solution (linked), is the kind of thing *requiring* comfortable knowledge of pointer-work to understand.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan correct my solution as early as possible please

Comment: @saimadan below BLUEPIXY already corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void sort(){
    node *temp, *push;
    node *tprev, *pprev;
    node *save;

    tprev = NULL;
    for (temp = p; temp != NULL; temp = temp->link){
        pprev = temp;
        for (push=temp->link; push != NULL; push = push->link){
            if (push->data < temp->data){
                save = temp->link;
                temp->link = push->link;
                if(save == push)
                    push->link = temp;
                else
                    push->link = save;
                if(pprev != temp)
                    pprev->link = temp;
                if(tprev)
                    tprev->link = push;
                else
                    p = push;
                save = temp;
                temp = push;
                push = save;
            }
            pprev = push;
        }
        tprev = temp;
    }
}
```