# Swap two nodes in a singly linked list

Tags: linked-list, pascal

How to switch two nodes in a singly linked list in pascal?

```
procedure List.switch(var n1,n2 : pNode);
var aux : pNode;
begin
  aux := n1;
  p1:= n2;
  n2 := aux;
end;
```

(Here pNode is a pointer on a node in the list.)

Nodes are defined like this:

```
pNode = ^Node;
Node = record
    data : data;
    next : pNode;
end;
```

This code doesn't work. It either doesn't compile, saying "Can't take the address of constant expressions", or just doesn't do anything. I guess it has to do with how pointers work...

I found relevant information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315914/swap-nodes-in-a-singly-linked-list), but I don't read C.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Can you show how your nodes are defined

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to just presume that your node definition was the same as the C code you linked. :-)

Comment: The code that doesn't compile isn't shown? Or where is the error?

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this would work:

```
function SwapNodes(first: pNode): pNode;
begin
  Result := first.next;
  first.next := Result.next;
  Result.next := first;
end;
```

Comment: I wasn't sure this would work in classic Pascal I don't remember quite that far back clearly - Delphi has spoiled me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for you. It uses a local variable of type Node (which is presumably what PNode is a pointer to) as a placeholder.

```
procedure List.Switch(NodeA, NodeB: PNode);
var
  Temp: Node;
begin
  Temp.Data := NodeB^.Data;
  Temp.Next := NodeB^.Next;
  NodeB^.Data := NodeA^.Data;
  NodeB^.Next := NodeA^.Next;
  NodeA^.Data := Temp.Data;
  NodeA^.Next := Temp.Next;
end;
```

Here's a version of it that isn't an object method, with a console app that tests it:

```
program Project1;

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  PNode = ^Node;
  Node = record
    Data: Integer;
    Next: PNode;
  end;

procedure Swap(NodeA, NodeB: PNode);
var
  Temp: Node;
begin
  Temp.Data := NodeB^.Data;
  Temp.Next := NodeB^.Next;
  NodeB^.Data := NodeA^.Data;
  NodeB^.Next := NodeA^.Next;
  NodeA^.Data := Temp.Data;
  NodeA^.Next := Temp.Next;
end;

var
  A, B: Node;
  pA, pB: PNode;

begin
  New(pA);
  pA^.Data := 1;
  pA^.Next := nil;
  New(pB);
  pB^.Data := 2;
  pB^.Next := @A;
  WriteLn('Before - pA^.Data: ', pA^.Data, ' pB^.Data: ', pB^.Data);
  Swap(pA, pB);
  WriteLn('After - pA^.Data: ', pA^.Data, ' pB^.Data: ', pB^.Data);    // Outputs 2 and 1
  Readln;
  Dispose(pA);
  Dispose(pB);
end.
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer, but it doesn't work for me. Strangely, one of the nodes is deleted from the list completely!

Comment: It works fine in the test app I provided. I can't explain why it doesn't work when you implement it in your code, because I can't see your code.

Comment: I just iterate over the nodes of the list to write them out. After the swap, one of the swapped elements is just omitted. Hmm...

Comment: I can't see your implementation of the list, how you're adding items or allocating memory, or any of that information. I've added a couple of lines of code to the test app above to demonstrate that both nodes are intact (but swapped) after the swap. Just to clarify: You're only using the List.switch function in your code, not the test app code that uses New and Dispose?

Comment: I see. Yes, I'm testing it on my code and am getting some strange behaviour here. The list is cut before the first swapped node and the node before the first swapped node points to the second swapped node. Maybe the trouble lies in my implementation, but I triple-checked it and don't think so.

Comment: Just try to load a list of integers, from a file, swap two elements and iterate trough it. You'll see it doesn't work for some reason... :(

Comment: I don't have **your code** for what a "list of integers" is, to "just load a list of integers from a file", your test file, and your code that does all of the other stuff. I can't debug it from here, I'm afraid. The code I posted clearly works to swap two nodes. Now you're throwing file I/O into the mix somewhere. I also don't have the code you're using to iterate - for all I know, it could be skipping a node. You're asking me to write additional code well out of the scope of the question asked here to debug an implementation I can't see; that seems a little unreasonable to me.

Comment: Actually, I don't know what your `list' is; it's clearly a class of some sort (maybe; it could be a record with methods, in recent versions of some Pascal dialects such as Delphi). What type is it? I also have no idea how you're allocating the nodes. As I said, I can't debug code I can't see.