# Move node to beginning of singly linked list

Tags: algorithm, sorting, linked-list, pascal, quicksort

In Pascal, when I have a singly linked list with nodes defined like this,

```
pNode = ^Node;
Node = record
    data : data;
    next : pNode;
end;
```

and when I iterate through the list like this

```
while y<>z do begin
        if y^.data < x^.data then begin
          { HERE I WOULD LIKE TO MOVE y IN FRONT OF X }
        end;
        y:=y^.next;
end;
```

where x is the pivot (beginning of the list), y is the 'index', z is the tail (the end) of the list (yes, I am trying to perform a quicksort on a singly linked list). How would I accomplish the task in the comment?

I made the procedure `insertAfter`:

```
procedure List.insertAfter(n : pNode; var what : data);
var newn : pNode;
begin
  new(newn);
  newn^.data := what;
  newn^.next := n^.next;
  n^.next := newn;
end;
```

and `insertInstead`

```
procedure List.insertInstead(n : pNode; var what : data);
begin
    List.insterAfter(n, n^.data);
    n^.data:=what;
end;
```

and similarly `deleteAfter(n : pNode)`

```
procedure List.deleteAfter(n : pNode);
var q : pNode;
begin
    q := n^.next;
    n^.next := n^.next^.next;
    dispose(q);
end;
```

and `delete(n : pNode)`

```
procedure List.delete(n : pNode);
begin
    if n^.next <> tail then begin
        n^.data := n^.next^.data;
        deleteAfter(n);
    end
    else begin
        dispose(tail);
        tail:=n;
        tail^.next := nil;
    end;
end;
```

Now when I put in the iteration, instead of the comment

```
list.insertInstead(x,y^.data);
list.delete(y);
```

, it doesn't work, presumably because `y^.next` now doesn't point to the same node as before the move.

So the question is: how do I move the node to the beginning with `y^.next` still pointing to the same node?

PS.: I have tried the obvious: using and auxiliary variable to store the actual value of y before the move, but it seems to change along with y.

Here is the original code: [Stack](http://tny.cz/7bdc1e2c), [List](http://tny.cz/ced16960), [Quicksort](http://tny.cz/6dbc9006).

Comment: There seems to be an error/mistype in List.delete. In the line "deleteAfter(p)", what is "p"?

Comment: @Penguino Edited. It wasn't the problem though (I am translating the code)

Comment: There is another 'typo/error' in List.delete. You write "n^.data := n^.next^.next;" Shouldn't this be "n^.data := n^.next^.data;"? Unless you copy real code (or take care to avoid errors in 'translation', it is difficult to tell what the original code does.

Comment: @Penguino Yes, it should and is now. Now I'm certain it is absolutely correct.

Comment: @Penguino I also added links to the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might see the problem. The first line of your insert code

```
 list.insertInstead(x,y^.data);
```

works fine. It puts a new node immediately after x and populates it with y's data (so you effectively now have a copy of node y after node x.

But I don't think the second line

```
 list.delete(y);
```

does what you want it to. It does 'remove' the node y from the list (as you want), but does so by moving data from the node following y into y's location, and deleting that node. So now y.next points at the node following the node following the original y. Maybe a diagram would help.

Before list.delete(y)

```
 node:     ... - y - a - b - c - ... - z
 data:     ... - Y - A - B - C - ... - Z
                     ^ 
                     y.next points here (data is A)
```

After list.delete(y)

```
 node:     ... - y - b - c - ... - z
 data:     ... - A - B - C - ... - Z
                     ^ 
                     y.next points here (data is B)
                 ^
                 y points here (data is A)
```

so if you 'increment y as in your line

```
 y:=y^.next;
```

in your iteration loop you will miss out on testing data A. You can fix that by removing the y:=y^.next; line. But then there will still be a problem with your while loop in the line

```
 while y<>z do begin
```

Because the pointer to node y doesn't change anymore (as you have removed y := y^.next), y will never equal z. The simplest (but possibly not the most elegant) way to fix this might be to replace the line with

```
 while y^.next <>z do begin
```

and add a final case to test the last node.

The main loop would then look like something like (without testing):

```
 while y^.next <> z do begin
         if y^.data < x^.data then begin
                 list.insertInstead(x,y^.data);
                 list.delete(y);
         end;
 end;
 if y^.data < x^.data then begin
         list.insertInstead(x,y^.data);
         list.delete(y);
 end;
```

or, by defining a new procedure

```
 procedure list.moveiflessthan(x,y : pnode);
 begin
      if y^.data < x^.data then begin
              list.insertInstead(x,y^.data);
              list.delete(y);
      end;
 end;
```

you get

```
 while y^.next <> z do
         if y^.data < x^.data then 
                 list.moveiflessthan(x,y);
 if y^.data < x^.data then
         list.moveiflessthan(x,y);
```

There may still be an end-case error if you reach the end of the list (I haven't checked) but I am sure you can work that out...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the easiest way is only to change (swap) the values of the nodes.

```
{ HERE I WOULD LIKE TO MOVE y IN FRONT OF X }
tmp := x^.data
x^.data := y^.data
y^data := tmp
```

UPDATE: Here is the similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1536046/2490538

Zdravím.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, but it doesn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214256/swap-two-nodes-in-a-singly-linked-list

Comment: If I understand well, You want to sort the nodes by the value.

Comment: That's the ultimate goal, but the problem here is the division step in quicksort, where I want to put all the elements smaller than the first one (pivot) in front of (before) it.

Comment: What about procedure which saves nodes data to an array, sorts the array and returns these values back to the list. If you operate with nodes, there is too much memory allocation. Use built in quicksort .)

Comment: Yes, that is a solution. But the whole point of working with a list in the first place is that list, unlike array, is a dynamic data structure. So you think it is impossible?

Comment: It is possible, but not necessary. I think it is better, to get the node values, sort them like array and then create new list or simply again traverse existing list and change values (in this case)

Note: You can create dynamic data structure using static data structure like array, for example Stack can be implemented with array.