# Swap two nodes in singly linked list

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list

I'm having trouble swapping nodes in a singly linked list. My code currently works when neither of the nodes is the start of the list.

EDIT: I'm learning about ADTs so I can't change what the function inputs and outputs.

```
typedef struct textbuffer *TB;

struct textbuffer {
    char *data;
    TB next;
};

void swapTB(TB tb, int pos1, int pos2) {
    if (tb == NULL || pos1 == pos2) return;
    int totalLines = linesTB(tb) - 1;
    if (pos1 < FIRST_LINE || pos1 > totalLines || pos2 < FIRST_LINE || pos2 > totalLines) {
        printf("Error: line number out of range, %d-%d.\n", FIRST_LINE, totalLines);
        abort();
    } else {
        TB all = tb;
        int i = 0;
        TB prevX = NULL;
        TB currX = tb;
        while (i != pos1) {
            prevX = currX;
            currX = currX->next;
            i++;
        }

        int j = 0;
        TB prevY = NULL;
        TB currY = tb;
        while (j != pos2) {
            prevY = currY;
            currY = currY->next;
            j++;
        }

        if (prevX != NULL) {
            prevX->next = currY;
        } else {
            all = currY; //update head of list
        }

        if (prevY != NULL) {
            prevY->next = currX;
        } else {
            all = currX; //update head of list
        }

        TB temp = currY->next;
        currY->next = currX->next;
        currX->next = temp;
    }
    //return all;
}
```

I know my way of swapping nodes is correct because if I change to function to return a TB (in this case, all) then it works.

My question is how to I do it with a void function and without changing what the function takes in? I think I need a head pointer? But how do I use that?

Comment: This code looks terribly complicated. BTW please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is `TB` an hide pointer? Otherwise its visibility/scope is limited to `swapTB` function.

Comment: Add those info into your post.

Comment: I chose to use a singly linked list so I wrote the struct that way, I don't know whether I should add a TB head inside?

Comment: Head node **must be** passed to that function. I'm not getting the question.

Comment: Side note: with a single while you can find both `pos1` and `pos2` nodes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap nodes in a singly-linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15315914/swap-nodes-in-a-singly-linked-list)

Comment: @LPs as in I use only int i = 0 or do I have to create another variable like int j = 0?

Comment: Your loop should test that `->next != NULL` or that `pos1` and `pos2` aren't found yet.

Answer (score 1):

Do two things:-
Passed address of your struct textbuffer in a function.

void swapTB(TB *tb, int pos1, int pos2)

in main() :-

swapTB(tb,pos1,pos2);

And also check your currx and curry NULL or not.

```
typedef struct node *TB;
struct node
{
    int data;
    TB next;
};

TB head=NULL;

void swapNodes(TB head_ref, int x, int y)
{
   if (x == y) return;
  head = head_ref;

   struct node *prevX = NULL, *currX = head_ref;
   while (currX && currX->data != x)
   {
       prevX = currX;
       currX = currX->next;
   }

   struct node *prevY = NULL, *currY = head_ref;
   while (currY && currY->data != y)
   {
       prevY = currY;
       currY = currY->next;
   }

   if (currX == NULL || currY == NULL)
       return;

   if (prevX != NULL)
       prevX->next = currY;
   else
       head = currY;

   if (prevY != NULL)
       prevY->next = currX;
   else
       head = currX;

   struct node *temp = currY->next;
   currY->next = currX->next;
   currX->next  = temp;

}

int main()
{
    TB start=NULL;
    // Create linked list here

    swapNodes(start, pos1, pos2);

    print_linkedlist(head);  // print the linked list after swap

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `TB **tb` --> `TB *tb`  ...an example of why is better to avoid hiding pointers with typedef

Comment: @LPs i am passing address of pointer and as i know we need double pointer to hold address of single pointer as i advised to OP to pass address of single pointer.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without changing void swapTB(TB tb, int pos1, int pos2)? because I'm learning about ADTs and that was what's provided

Comment: @LPs oops, i didn't observe OP had edited his question.

Comment: @kuroholic you can use global object but it is not good programming. To pass reference is a best option in your case.

Comment: @SumitGemini so would that be function pointers? can you give me a very small example?

Comment: @kuroholic function pointer? no my mean was to pass a object address in a function as a call by reference. that i have posted in answer.

Comment: @SumitGemini sorry I'm still not getting what you mean. I see that you have changed the function to take in TB *tb, but I can't change that.

Comment: @kuroholic i have modified answer, I have to be taken global variable.

Comment: @SumitGemini THANK YOU SO MUCH