# Swapping head of linked list with a link within it?

Tags: c, function, linked-list, singly-linked-list

To clarify the title: I am traversing the linked list like so `*head=(*head)->next` because it is a function. In my function I pick my **current** `head` and another link that is between the **current** `head` and the end of the list to swap with.

What I want is to make a function that would swap the `head` and the link (not only data) knowing that all the conditions of the swap are met; meaning the link isn't the current `head` or the link isn't a `NULL`. Can it be done like that or do I have to try something else?

Thanks in advance.

since my question is unclear, ill give you the problem.

I need to make a function like this:

```
void intertwine(cvor **head)
```

I recieve a linked list with random numbers. What i need to do is to swap the links until it look like so: uneven number, even number, uneven, even etc.

i must respect the order the uneven and even are in.

if there are no equal amout of even and uneven just leave them in the order they are in within the list.

here are 2 examples:

input: 11, 7, 5, 16, 12, 15, 17, 13, 10, 4, 1

output:11, 16, 7, 12, 5, 10, 15, 4, 17, 13, 1

input: 1, 3, 2, 4

output: 1, 2, 3, 4

my current code looks like this(**unfinished**)

edit2: sorry forgot the language barrier

```
typedef struct atom{
    int el;
    struct atom *next;
} cvor;

void intertwine (cvor **head){
    cvor *pom,int br=1;

    pom=*head;
    while(*head){
        if((*head)->el%2==(br%2)){
            pom=(*head)->next;
            while(pom){
                if(pom->el%2==(br+1)%2)break;
                pom=pom->next;
            }
            if(pom==NULL) return;
```

Here at the end is when the swap I want would occour.

Comment: `*head=(*head)->next` is generally `head = head->next`. You use `.` for an object, and `->` for a pointer to the object. Also, in a linked list, never overwrite the head node, just the pointer.

Comment: You really should not use `*head` when iterating over the list, as that will change where `*head` is pointing. Which means you will lose your actual head.

Comment: And for linked list operations, no matter what they are, I always suggest you draw them all down on paper. Draw a few lists, with small squares being the nodes, and with arrows being the links between the nodes. Then "perform" the operations step by step, drawing and redrawing between each little step. Once you think you got it all right on paper, then try to translate the drawings into code.

Comment: @And Ro clarify me one thing. You want to make some element of the linked-list as head and head to repalce that or just the data swapping?

Comment: It's somewhat unclear what you want. Please show us a drawing and/or your existing code. Overall answer to your question (if I understood it correctly) is: yes it can be done.

Comment: @ satyaGolladi i want to replace the current head and a link, not the data. Thank you all for help

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal and I understand, however this is a function, so it does not overwrite right?

Comment: The pointer value passed does not get overwritten. The value at the pointer does. You should read up on how exactly pointers work in functions.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've updated it and added the problem so you can understand more clearly, can you explain how can it be done?

Comment: Are there any reason that you doesn't do a simple swap of data and leave the linked list unchanged? When data is just a simple `int` it's much easier to swap data

Comment: @4386427 I know it is much simpler to this, however that isn't what the problem wants - it specifically needs the link swap

Comment: See this for swapping two nodes in a linked list https://stackoverflow.com/a/15316061/4386427

Comment: @4386427 a worthwhile post, thank you, however it doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved if you write a function that can move one element in a linked list in front of another element in the same linked list.

As input the function should take

- A pointer to the `head` pointer'
- A pointer b to the element to be moved
- A pointer a to the element that b shall be moved in front of

Like

```
void move_b_in_front_of_a(cvor **head, cvor* b, cvor* a) { ... }
```

When calling the function is required that

- Both `a` and `b` points to elements in the list `*head`
- That `a` is located before `b` in the list

The implementation could be like:

```
void move_b_in_front_of_a(cvor **head, cvor* a, cvor* b)
{
  // Find the element just before a
  cvor* a_prev = find_element_before(head, a);

  // Find the element just before b (start from a)
  cvor* b_prev = find_element_before(a, b);
  if (b_prev == NULL) { .... add error handling ....}

  // Take b out of the list
  b_prev->next = b->next;

  // Insert b in front of a
  if (a_prev == NULL)
  {
    (*head) = b;
  }
  else
  {
    a_prev->next = b;
  }
  b->next = a;
}
```

In the above code I used the function

```
cvor* find_element_before(cvor* l, cvor* e)
{
  // Add code to find the element just before e in the list l
  // Return NULL if e is first element
  // Add error handling if element e isn't found

  ...
  ...

  return pointer_to_element_just_before_e;
}
```

that you'll need to implement.

When you have these two functions it should be pretty easy to implement the `intertwine` function.

Here are some pseudo code for the function that might get you started:

```
current_element = *head
expected-type = odd
loop:
    if current_element is expected-type
        toggle expected-type
        current_element = next
        if current_element is NULL return
    else
        find_element with_correct_type
        if no element found return
        move found_element in front of current_element  (use above function)
        current_element = found_element
```